# Angular2: How to implement more than 2 method

Tags: angular

how can i implement Oninit & Ondestroy. I tried below but didn't work for me.

I am extracting id from URL for that i want to use OnDestroy to avoid memory problem and need to call service onInit

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { DetailService } from '../detail.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail-page',
  templateUrl: './detail-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail-page.component.css'],
  providers: [DetailService]
})
export class DetailPageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
detailData: any;
id:string;
private subscription: Subscription;
  constructor(private detailService: DetailService, private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.subscription = this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(
      (param: any) => this.id = param['id']
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
        this.detailService.getDetailData()
  .subscribe(
    data => this.detailData = data
  );
}  

ngOnDestroy(){
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}

}
```

Comment: Can you add the full code? Where are the methods?

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Comment: Just implement `ngOnDestroy()` like you did with `ngOnInit()`. What's the problem?

Comment: I made changes and trying to print **this.id = param['id']** in **html** but not getting anything .... can you please suggest

Comment: what is the issue you have. seems that you do everything right

Comment: when i print this.id = param['id'] in html .... i get blank value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code syntax looks fine. Did you include DetailService into the snippet?

Notice: Unsubscribing from Activated route [is not necessary](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#route-parameters):

`The ActivatedRoute and its observables are insulated from the Router itself. The Router destroys a routed component when it is no longer needed and the injected ActivatedRoute dies with it.`

UPDATED:
Instead of `activatedRoute.queryParams` you might want to use `activatedRoute.params`

```
  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.params = route.params.subscribe(
      params => this.id = params['id']
    );
  }
```

UPDATE2:

- Use `params` when it's a part of the path, e.g `{path: 'page/:id'}`
- Use `queryParams` when it's an optional query param, e.g: `page?id=1`

More info is [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

Comment: DetailService into the snippet? can you please elaborate this as i am unaware of term snippet

Comment: Please don't mind, I meant the StackOverflow snippet.
Have you figured out your issue?
Btw instead of `activatedRoute.queryParams` you might want to use `activatedRoute.params`

Comment: i get "Property 'Params' does not exist on type 'ActivatedRoute'.
any
"

Comment: Thanks it worked, what is the issue with queryparams? what is the difference between queryparams and query